# How to transform Dirac fermion coupled with $SU(2)/Z_2$ gauge field to the real fermion coupled with $SO(3)$?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, group-theory, group-representations, spinors, yang-mills

For instance, I am considering a free (3+1)-D Dirac fermion coupled with $SU(2)$ (fundamental representation) gauge field. Then I do a "gauging" the center $Z_2$ to the associated principal bundle by identifying the element $g\in SU(2)$ with its opposite: $g\sim-g$. Therefore, in the point of view of the group theory, the gauge field should be $SO(3)$ due to the isomorphism between the $SU(2)/Z_2$ and $SO(3)$.

However, I have no idea how to derive the field theory coupled with $SO(3)$ directly from my original model. (At the beginning, I guessed the theory might be Majorana fermion coupled to $SO(3)$ gauge field, but the degree of freedom does not seem to match that of the original model.) Thus, could you give me some idea about this derivation?

Comment: I have an idea about my question. If we assume that our problem has a well-defined field theory model coupled to $SO(3)$ gauge field, then the solution seems unique. From the point of view of the dimension of the representation, the only two possible solutions are just the (1)+(3) representation of $SO(3)$ or (1)+(1)+(1)+(1) where (1) and (3) are spin-0 and spin-1 representation, respectively. In addition, considering the number of the nonzero generators, which should be 4, we can only have (1)+(3) representation as solution.